# Error in qx.io.remote.transport.Iframe.send() using IE8

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8, qooxdoo

Please find below the code in qx.io.remote.transport.Iframe.send(). I'm using qooxdoo 0.8.3, by the way...

```
var vFormFields = this.getFormFields();

for (var vId in vFormFields)
{
  var vField = document.createElement("textarea");
  vField.name = vId;
  vField.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vFormFields[vId]));
  this.__form.appendChild(vField);
}
```

I'm getting an "Object not supported" error on the 5th (and last) this.__form.appendChild(vField) when I use Windows 7, IE 8.0.7600.16385. I've tried using Windows XP, IE 8.0.6001.18702...and it works. I've also tried using Chrome, Firefox and older versions of IE and I haven't encountered any problem.

I don't have the slightest idea whether this problem should be addressed by the application code, qooxdoo framework or IE. Any idea on how to resolve this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Update: I've migrated to 1.4.1 and the problem persists. The error occurs in IE8 Standards mode. It works with the other modes, including IE8 Compatibility View.

Comment: In which mode does the error occur? (IE8 Standards Mode, IE7 Standards Mode or Quirks Mode)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a current qooxdoo, which is [1.4.1](http://qooxdoo.org/about/release_notes/1.4.1) btw?! If you do make sure you go through the migration, as given in the [release notes](http://qooxdoo.org/about/release_notes/1.4) and [manual](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.4.x/pages/migration/migration_guide.html).